# Sphinx: local conf for a page?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

Can I have page-local value of a conf variable (normally found in `conf.py`)?

For example, I have

```
hyphenator_language = "en-us"
```

in `conf.py`. Can I have it

```
hyphenator_language = "ru"
```

for a given ReST page of the sphinx document?

Comment: Maybe you can use a custom hyphenator for those pages?

Comment: once you were able to say $ sphinx-build -D hyphenator_language="..."
I can not test it right now, but is it that what you are looking for or am i totally wrong?

Comment: @FelixLama: but it will set the var for the whole doc. While I want to change the var for a single page.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no general way to do this for an arbitrary config variable, but in your case, for hyphenator in particular, you have a couple of options:

- Convince the author of the Sphinx hyphenator extension to add support for a directive that sets the panguage per page.
- Since the hyphenator extension uses hyphenator.js, which is a JS library, you could probably use some raw html (using the `raw` directive) to inject a script tag that would set the language on that page.
- Create a custom template (or extend your existing one) to contain the logic which sets the language for the page.